# django test non-field validation errors

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a custom validation function, but I'd like to test that it's throwing the errors it's supposed to using the unittest framework provided by Django.

I could call the function directly and test it that way, but that doesn't ensure that it's being used properly in the view (ie: I want to do an integration test).

What is the django way to test non field specific validation errors?

For example, an email field will test is the text entered is a valid email address, but a non-field error will display above the form, with no relationship to any one field. It would, for instance, say that that email address is already registered.

When testing applications, how do you test these non-field validation errors?

Answer (score 6):

You can test a form for errors by using [`assertFormError()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertFormError).

> Asserts that a field on a form raises the provided list of errors when rendered on the form.

Please note that the form name has to be the name of the form in the `context` not the actual form you are using for validation.

You can use it as follows for `non_field_errors` (general errors not related to any field):

```
self.assertFormError(response, 'form', None, 'Some error')
```

You can test for a specific field error as follows:

```
self.assertFormError(response, 'form', 'field_name', 'Some error')
```

You can also pass in a tuple of errors to test against.

```
errors = ['some error 1', 'some error 2']
self.assertFormError(response, 'form', 'field_name', errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

write a custom function that validates the fields and call it instead of form.is_valid().

Django docs provides a detialed description about this. check the below link.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning

For Example:
from django import forms

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def clean_message(self):
    message = self.cleaned_data['message']
    num_words = len(message.split())
    if num_words < 4:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Not enough words!")
    return message
```

Herr clean_message will be my custom validation method

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear, I'll update it. I want to know how to test that the custom validation is working using Djangos unittest framework.