# Django form test non-field errors

Tags: python, django, testing

I'd like to ask for a method to check if any kind of non-field errors was raised during form validation in Django. So far I found solution to [do this during view testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34084632/2550466). Well, it wasn't what I was looking for since I'm interested in *doing it at form tests*.

I know the way to look for fields' errors:

```
class FormTest(TestCase)
    def test_fields_errors(self):
        """
        Suppose form has one field which has to be filled
        """

        form = TestForm()
        form.full_clean()

        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
        self.assertIsInstance(
            form.errors.as_data()['required_field'][0],
            ValidationError
        )
        self.assertEquals(
            form.errors['deadline_datetime'][0],
            'This field must not be empty'
        )
```

Is there any way to do this when we deal with non-field errors?

Comment: You should be able to access `form.non_field_errors()`?

Comment: Oh, you're right. Looks like I tried to reinvent the wheel. Thank you for your nice and simple answer

Answer (score 2):

I answer my own question, but I also wanna start discussion if there is any better solution

With small help of debugger, I found that non-field errors appear in `form.errors` as well. But this time there wasn't any dict key named like non-field errors. All I found was a bit strange key `__all__`, but it allowed me to access demanded errors:

```
class FormTest(TestCase)
    def test_fields_errors(self):
    """
    Suppose form has two fields and either one has to be filled
    """

    form = TestForm()
    form.full_clean()

    self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
    self.assertIsInstance(
            form.errors.as_data()['__all__'][0],
            ValidationError
    )
    assertEquals(
        errors['__all__'][0],
        'Fill at least one field'
    )
```

So, I was able to find the error I was looking for during testing non-field errors raise.

Comment: It's been over 3 years since your post, so I'm hoping you found your answer. However, if someone else stumbles upon this, there's a method called [assertFormErrors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertFormError). This can be used with the field name as None for non-field errors. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34084632/4316181) to [django test non-field validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991239/django-test-non-field-validation-errors) for details.